# Adding Views - VS Adds Scaffolding and NuGets

Tags: mvc, visual-studio

Can people suggest a good way to add views to a project in Visual Studio? The standard MVC way adds scaffolding (Folders named for controllers) and `NuGet packages` (MVC, Razor, WebPages, etc...) I'm stuck copying existing views and renaming, or adding a text file and adding the `.cshtml` extension. There must be a way to tell Visual Studio to turn off the `scaffolding/NuGet` stuff.

Comment: Is your question specifically about turning off this Visual Studio behavior? Or is it, in general, about the best ways to add new views in VS, without scaffolding being applied?

Comment: Both. My ideal solution would be to turn that behavior off, but if it depends on the type of project I create, I am well into a project already and cant start from scratch, so how do I avoid it?

Comment: If you don't have MVC, Razor and other NuGet packages installed, how can are you creating views without VS complaining about missing classes, namespaces, etc.? Have you considered just installing the packages matching the versions used by Sitecore?

Comment: I am manually adding dll references to ensure I have the correct version for my version of Sitecore. That is, the dlls that come with a vanilla Sitecore install.

Answer (score 9):

With `MVC 5`, you should have the option to add an `MVC 5 View Page`, like so,

[image: Add MVC 5 View Page context menu]

Using this option gives you a simple popup to type in a name, then it generates a `cshtml` file with no scaffolding.

```razor
@{
    Layout = null;
}
<!DOCTYPE html>

<html>
<head>
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width" />
    <title></title>
</head>
<body>
    <div>

    </div>
</body>
</html>
```

Alternately, you can select MVC Partial Page which just generates an empty .cshtml file.

**MSDN reference:** https://www.asp.net/mvc/overview/getting-started/introduction/adding-a-view

Comment: Alternatively, choose the `MVC 5 Partial Page (Razor)` option to get a cleaner starting point.

Comment: Added to the answer!

Comment: WRONG!!! Still adds Nugets.

Answer (score 3):

If you use the default Web Applications with MVC project template, I'm not sure whether you can turn off this behaviour. However, you could potentially use Sitecore Rocks to create the files for you instead.

Comment: I find Sitecore Rocks to be excruciatingly slow. I conceptually like what it can do but am way too impatient.